# How to return rows with duplicate values where a certain condition is met?

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks a bit like this:

```
country | group | offer | type | list
--------|-------|-------|------|-----
UK      | A     | 1     | AA   | 1
UK      | A     | 2     | BB   | 1
UK      | A     | 3     | CC   | 2
IE      | A     | 4     | AA   | 2
IE      | A     | 5     | BB   | 2
IE      | A     | 6     | CC   | 1
UK      | B     | 7     | AA   | 3
UK      | B     | 8     | BB   | 4
UK      | B     | 9     | CC   | 4
```

I want to return all rows where the following is true:

- Type = CC
- List value is shared with a row of type AA or BB that has the same
  group and country

So for example, my desired result would look like this:

```
country | group | offer | type | list
--------|-------|-------|------|-----
UK      | B     | 9     | CC   | 4
```

This row would be returned because it's type is CC, and it has the same list number as other rows whose country is UK and group is B.

Does anyone know how this can be done please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `EXISTS` with required conditions like this

```
SELECT 
    t.*
FROM t
WHERE t.type = 'CC' 
      AND EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM t tt
          WHERE tt.type IN ('AA', 'BB') 
                AND tt.list = t.list
                AND tt."group" = t."group"
                AND tt.country = t.country
          )
```

Output

| country | group | offer | type | list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | B | 9 | CC | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PMd1kI82)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your SQL Dialect's concatenation symbol is `||` you can use SQL like this:

```
Select * 
from mytable 
where type = 'CC' 
  and list||'-'||group||'-'||country in (select list||'-'||group||'-'||country 
                                         from mytable 
                                         where type in ('AA', 'BB'))
```

SQL Server Version:

```
Select * 
from t a
where type = 'CC' 
  and concat(list,'-',a."group",'-',country) in (select concat(list,'-',b."group",'-',country) 
                                                from t b 
                                                where type in ('AA', 'BB'))
```

Comment: I'm using - character to separate column values because I want not to take possible values that seems to be equals but are different. For example, '1' concat '11' is the same value of '11' concat '1'.

Comment: You can also use other sql commands like exists to do this, but implementation depends on your specific dialect, so db2 is different from sql server and so on.

Comment: Why make it a string instead of doing something like `AND (list,group,country) IN (SELECT list, group, country FROM ...)`?

Comment: Another possiblity if you don't care about repetitions: Select distinct a.*
from t a join t b on a.list=b.list and a."group"=b."group" and a.country=b.country and 
a.type='CC' and b.type in('AA','BB')

Comment: Ah, I answered my own question. Apparently the syntax I used above is only for Oracle

Comment: Concatenating values like that is risky, and also spoils index usage.